# Spring MVC: @RequestParam only for POST requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I'm build a Portlet application using Spring as my framework. A require a `@RequestParam` argument in a `@RenderMapping` method, so I actually do it like this:

```
@RenderMapping
public String iDoSomething(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String theParameter,
        ModelMap modelMap, PortletSession session, Principal principal)
```

I also use the parameter in a @ModelAttribute method, like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("imInModel")
public AClass iCreateAModel(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String theParameter,
        BindingResult bindingResult, PortletSession session,
        Principal principal, PortletRequest request) {
```

Now, I want to only have the parameter passed to my methods only if the HTTP method used is POST, and ignore it if the method is GET. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't use Spring MVC in a portlet before so I may be irrelevant here, but I don't think portlets are meant to understand the difference between GET and POST requests. It's not part of their request/response model. Portlets use things like RenderRequests, ActionRequests, ResourceRequests, etc. 

I'm assuming you're trying to implement some AJAX functionality. That's one of the main use cases of the serveResource method in a portlet. Is using serveResource to 'differentiate' between your types of requests a viable solution for you?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is do certain logic when a Parameter comes from a Render URL or by a Form submission